# How do we only Allow Users/Groups from specific Domains(ours or theirs) to access ssh/sftp?

Tags: centos, ssh, sshd, sftp

Question is:
How do we only allow specific users coming from either their domain or using our domain in an appropriate way (SSH/SFTP)?
E.G.

```
jonnycustomer@ourdomain.com coming from customersIPaddress is Denied
and
jonnycustomer@ourdomain.com coming from randomIPaddress is not allowed
and
jonnycustomer@ourotherdomain.com is not allowed
```

In Centos 7, our sshd_config has this additional config:

```
Match Address 192.168.1.0/24
        AllowUsers bob trev
Match Address *,!192.168.1.0/24
        AllowGroups sftpgroup
Match All
PermitRootLogin no
```

sftpgroup is a group of our customers, that have their own root directories.
but the above config UNFORTUNATELY Allows our customers' "employees" to login from unknown ip addresses, and it also allows them to use one of our other domains to login.

I tried this, and external users/groups stopped working:

```
Match Address 192.168.1.0/24
    AllowUsers bob trev
Match Address *,!192.168.1.0/24
    AllowUsers customer1@ourdomain.com
    AllowGroups sftponly
Match All
PermitRootLogin no
```

NB: bob and trev are our employees who only access from internally (they are not in the sftpgroup)

Answer (score 1):

You could roll back your `sshd_config` changes and simply use `/etc/hosts.allow`. On your distro it could be `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`.

For example, with FreeBSD you would use:

```
sshd : <ip of allowed> : allow
sshd : <another ip> : allow
sshd : ALL : deny
```

Be sure to add the `deny` rule at the end!